Implementing Object#tap with Typescript "this"
Since migrating over from Ruby to JS, I've become very used to having a "tap" global around that massively simplifies certain types of imperative code:
Object.prototype.tap = function(fn) {
  fn(this);
  return this;
};

For example, I can use it to construct divs, or console.log a misbehaving method
navBar.append(createElement('div').tap(div => {
  div.classList = 'food-items'
  div.append(createElement('span').tap(s => s.textContent = 'Pasta'));
});

user.withProperties({"a": 123}).tap(console.log).save();

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to get Typescript to understand this. So far I've figured out the use of declare global and interface Object to extend the global Object type:
declare global {
  interface Object { 
    tap(fn: (self: this) => void): this
  }
}

But this doesn't work for derived types, even though this should let us use derived types:
"test".tap(t => console.log(t.indexOf("t")));

Property 'indexOf' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

For some reason, even though "test" is inheriting the tap type correctly, this is still set to the base Object type. Does anyone know a way I can dynamically access the "current type" on a Typescript interface to fix this?

Unrelated to your TypeScript question, but if you mess with Object.prototype (and you really shouldn't) at least make the method non-enumerable. Also notice that you can use appendChild which returns its argument, so const div = navBar.appendChild(createElement('div')); div.classList = 'food-items'; ….

see the linked q/a this duplicates above. Using that answer here gives this version; caveats about modifying native prototypes still apply.

Thanks a ton! Didn't even occur to me that I could use this parameters like that.

@Bergi I'm not sure anybody is using for ... in these days. Enumerable properties have gone the way of the dodo, now that for ... of exists. But if I run into any issues with it I'll be sure to keep that in mind (So far I've only had one issue with a library that was using the in operator, and making tap non-enumerable wouldn't even really help with that)

@nightpool Yes, for … in … is still in use; it's much easier to use than for … of Object.keys(…).
